# How do i create a datatable submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Assume the following sketch

[image]

A and B are submit button but bootstrapped. each row must have those buttons and the table is a JQuery datatable, data for the table comes as Json. Assume A and B are for Edit and delete.. how do i add bootstrapped A and B buttons to each row like in the image?

Comment: Why can you not just add it? Expand your question?

Comment: You mean how will you create a repeater sort of thing ?

Comment: @TusharGupta I don't know if this got anything to do with ASP.NET data control. He said that he used jquery data table, and retrieve the rows by ajax. Don't you think?

Comment: http://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/envelopeInTable.html

Comment: I said whether he like to have a repeater sort of functionality ... I never assumed...I asked the question\

Comment: @TusharGupta this is for an MVC app so its jquery and yes data comes as json in ajax call

Comment: Yes that's y i have asked...You have display templates in MVC for the sam

Comment: @TusharGupta thanks you have solved the problem! : )

Answer (score 0):

I presume as per our discussion in comments, you need to repeat the elements. In MVC we have Display Templates , which acts like repeaters and will cater your need.